# Slack API method to send "typing"

Tags: asynchronous, slack-api, slack

I have a very slow bot, because it performs time-consuming operations behind every message response, and sometimes it is just annoying for a user to send a message and wait for 2–3 seconds until the response has come. I'd like to send "typing" event right away until the real message is ready. But I don't see such method in the Slack API reference. Does it even exist? Maybe I could use a workaround to achieve that? Has anybody solved a similar problem?

Comment: You should be able to do that by sending [this](https://api.slack.com/events/user_typing) event (with the appropriate parameters) via the RTM API.

Comment: Another way of doing this, which I personally prefer, is by adding emoji to the user's message, as explained at the bottom of this [medium](https://medium.com/@vijayssundaram/oh-hi-there-bot-3f7468f9bdda) article.

Answer (score 2):

#### Using [@slack/client](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@slack/client)

Assuming you have a working RtmClient instance…

```
var slack = new RtmClient(token, {
  // your params
});
```

…and a valid channel ID, this should work:

```
slack.sendTyping(channelId);
```

#### REST API

From [the docs](https://api.slack.com/rtm#typing_indicators):

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "type": "typing",
    "channel": "C024BE91L"
}
```

Note: I'm using the client, and haven't bothered reading the API docs yet, so I've no idea what the `id` field does here.